# Magento 2.3.4 - Server temp folder gets full because of SQL queries

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, database

I am using Magento 2.3.4, and the server temp folder gets full because of SQL queries. I am looking for someone who can optimize SQL server and queries from Magento 2. The below error appears when the site crashes.

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1021 Disk full (/dev/shm/#sql_2e1b28_7.MAI); waiting for someone to free some space... (errno: 28 "No space left on device"), query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `eav_attribute` AS `main_table`
INNER JOIN `eav_entity_type` AS `entity_type` ON main_table.entity_type_id = entity_type.entity_type_id
LEFT JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` ON main_table.attribute_id = eav_entity_attribute.attribute_id
INNER JOIN `catalog_eav_attribute` AS `additional_table` ON main_table.attribute_id = additional_table.attribute_id WHERE (`entity_type_code` = 'catalog_product') AND ((`additional_table`.`is_used_in_grid` = 1)) GROUP BY `main_table`.`attribute_id`

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Can someone help me

Answer (score 0):

this is usually if you have filled the /tmp. Was a server backup running at a similar time or had you used all innodes?